# How can I have user registration verify a whether a new user is listed in a table of pre-approved users?

Tags: user-registration

I only want existing customers to be able to register.  I have a table of valid customers, so I just need a hook to interrupt the registration process with "Sorry, an account with that number does not exist."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`registration_errors`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/registration_errors/) filter, which native errors go through and which allows you to provide your own. Returning filled in `WP_Error` object in this filter will smoothly prevent user from being created.

The one downside is that that filter is not passed much additional data — only login and email. You will probably have to fish your custom data out of global `$_POST` state for the check.

Comment: What about adding an action on register_post?  Is that equivalent?

Comment: These two hooks are right next to each other. The difference is that `register_post` is an action that won't stop the process, `registration_errors` actually allows you to smoothly customize the error message and prevent registration from proceeding.

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  One question, is there a state diagram of hooks for wordpress?  Something that tells me which hooks are called under which circumstances.

Comment: Way too much of a mess. Dumping it to figure for specific task is common practice. Some dev helper plugins, such as Query Monitor, will give you a list of hooks fired for starters.